# scrollIntoView() does not work in Salesforce Mobile App

Tags: lightning-web-components, scrolling

I have this line in my code:
`this.template.querySelector('.some-class').scrollIntoView();` and it works on desktops (at least it scrolls a bit) but doesn't work in Salesforce Mobile App at all.
Do you have any known workarounds to make it working on both desktops and mobiles? I need to bring certain div into the view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an object with some parameters: element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work as well (it does on desktop, but not in the SF Mobile App on iOS)

Comment: Interesting that exact line is working for me on SF Mobile App on iOS so there might be something more going on.